# How do I add this Change Log library to my current Android project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

Okay, so I'm having difficulties implementing this Change log library into my android app in eclipse: https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/changeloglib

I tried using the clone url and importing the library into eclipse and then going into the properties of my android project and adding it as a library but that didn't work. I do not have Maven installed nor do I know anything about it. Is there a way I can just get a jar of this library somewhere? Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Did you read this?
https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/changeloglib/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md#reference-this-project-as-a-library-in-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its most likely not setup as an Android Library project and that is why it can't be accessed that way.

You can create the jar yourself though by using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11289115/1784299 eclipse itself or running the jar command in a terminal. (Eclipse might be a little more user friendly if you don't use the terminal.

I would however highly recommend learning how to incorporate Maven in your projects because it is a huge time saver. If you migrate to Android Studio then Maven will become your best friend.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I managed to get it to work. I'll look into Maven!

Comment: It is not correct. You can't use a jar in this case, because the library uses some resources (as layouts and styles) that will not be packaged in a jar file.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I didn't take the time to look at the library, but obviously since you are the creator you are correct. You should follow his comment on your question!

Answer (score 0):

I answer here to help other devs with the same issue.

The library is built with the Android Studio folder structure.
I highly recommend to use the gradle build system to work.

Hovewer, you **can build it locally with Eclipse**.

All required steps are described here:
https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/changeloglib/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md#reference-this-project-as-a-library-in-eclipse.

It can be valid for a lot of libraries.

Eclipse uses `src` and `res` as source folders. Android Studio instead uses `src/main/java` and `src/main/res` as source folders.
So you have to mark the **`java`** folder as source (right click on folder -> Build-Path -> use as source folder)

Comment: I would agree with Gabriele seeing as he is the creator! This library has dependencies that are required to be build with gradle/maven