# Creating a JAR file and using it in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar

There are no good tutorials about creating a **JAR** file. I'm trying to create a **JAR** file and use it in different projects. I can create a class without an `Activity` as a library project in format of `ClassName.java`. However, I tried to create **JAR** files many times, but I could not succeed. Please help me step by step creating a **JAR** file.

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712714/how-to-make-a-jar-out-from-an-android-studio-project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288622/create-jar-for-android-project-in-eclipse

Comment: - This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712714/how-to-make-a-jar-out-from-an-android-studio-project) describes how to create a jar from a android studio project.
- This [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) describes exactly how to create jar files basically.
- This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library) describes how to use jars in other android studio projects. I hope it will help you